# Where does the value of $Form come from, when using a standard SilverStripe template?

Tags: forms, silverstripe

The Page Layout template for the "simple" theme (the default) contains:

```
<% include SideBar %>
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <h1>$Title</h1>
        <div class="content">$Content</div>
    </article>
        $Form
        $CommentsForm
</div>
```

Where does the value of $Form come from? ie to make use of it, what do I need to do?

Is it intended that I define a function Form() within the page controller that returns the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bit of an oddity. $Form is used by the Security controller, which is invoked in login situations (/Security/login, /Security/lostpassword, etc..) and because those templates can be themed, it assumes that you have a $Form variable somewhere in your template that indicates where the form should render.

You only need it in your Page.ss template, as the Security controller just renders a generic Page.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in Silverstripe that extends `ViewableData` basically doubles as a ViewModel. This includes DataObject and Controller. So things that are publicly accessible on these objects are exposed to the View layer and callable as template variables (be they properties or methods).

**Where does the value of $Form come from? ie to make use of it, what do I need to do?**
So basically yes, your assumption is correct. If you define `public function Form()` (which returns a Form instance) in the page controller class you want the form to show on, it will render a form on the template (for all pages of that type).

**Is it intended that I define a function Form() within the page controller that returns the form?**
What UncleCheese intends to say in his answer is that the variable name $Form is arbitrary. Your method could for instance be named ContactForm(), in which case you'd need to give the template $ContactForm to show the form (be sure that the second parameter to Form constructor reflects this too - http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/forms/introduction/ using - `__FUNCTION__` is a great way to avoid this gotcha).

Form() however does not appear as a function by default in page.php, nor in `ContentController`, etc. The `Security` controller however uses Page.ss to render (when you have the CMS module installed) - thus meaning if you do not have $Form in Page.ss somewhere, you will never be able to log in. So it's important to keep this unless you also define a Security.ss to make the login/lostpassword/etc. pages different to the normal Page.ss layout (in which case that template needs $Form).